# Use Accumulate while creating Table

Tags: syntax, list-manipulation

Can I somehow create a list and its cumulative sum at the same time, e.g. with `Table`: Now I do it in two steps

```
marsYr = 686.9726;
marsYrInt = 687;
startId = {520, 585};
mYrLen = Table[
  If[(Floor[(marsYrInt - marsYr)*(i)] - 
       Floor[(marsYrInt - marsYr)*(i - 1)] == 1) ∧ (i > 0), 
   marsYrInt - 1, marsYrInt], {i, 0, 80, 1}]
Accumulate@mYrLen
```

Then I would need to join the two lists, but can this be done within one "step", eg. within the table?

Also, would it be possible to use this `Accumulate` within the `Table` to control the upper bound of the generated table - i.e. continue with the table while the accumulate of current i is smaller than a certain value.

Comment: When you say *"join the two lists"* are you seeking a list of pairs of the item and its accumulation or a list with row one the items and row two the accumulation.

Comment: @Edmund are those two just a transpose? Then it would not matter. What I find more interesting is the second part, if it would be possible to generate the list only until the accumulate is smaller than certain number. In my code, I hardcoded 80 but in fact, the number of list items depends on the accumulated value. Do you think this is doable without loops?

Answer (score 2):

This creates `mYrLen` and `accu = Accumulate@mYrLen` "at one go"; I haven't tested its efficiency though - it might occur that you initial approach is faster.

```
marsYr = 686.9726;
marsYrInt = 687;
startId = {520, 585};
mYrLen = {};
accu = {0};
Do[If[(Floor[(marsYrInt - marsYr)*(i)] - 
      Floor[(marsYrInt - marsYr)*(i - 1)] == 1) \[And] (i > 
     0), {AppendTo[mYrLen, marsYrInt - 1]; 
   AppendTo[accu, Last@accu + marsYrInt - 1]}, {AppendTo[mYrLen, 
    marsYrInt]; AppendTo[accu, Last@accu + marsYrInt]}], {i, 0, 80, 1}]
accu = Drop[accu, 1];
```

Check:

```
accu == Accumulate@mYrLen
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

You may use `FoldList`.

With

```
foo[i_] := 
 If[(Floor[(marsYrInt - marsYr)*(i)] - Floor[(marsYrInt - marsYr)*(i - 1)] == 1) ∧ (i > 0),
  marsYrInt - 1,
  marsYrInt
  ]
```

Then

```
Rest@FoldList[
  With[{v = foo@#2}, {v, #1[[-1]] + v}] &,
  {0, 0},
  Range[80]]
```

Will give the list pairs of the value and the accumulation at that point in the list.

Hope this helps.